# Get Value in Deep Object/Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the Twitter Api PHP library which returns the following object fine in my controller:

```
$tw_trends = $this->twitter->trends();

[
    {
        "trends": [
            {
                "name": "Bill Cosby",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Bill+Cosby%22",
                "promoted_content": null,
                "query": "%22Bill+Cosby%22",
                "tweet_volume": 229907
            },
            ...
```

However, when I pass the `$tw_trends` to my view and try and do the following `foreach`, I get an error. How can I access the `name` value in the above object?

```
@foreach ($tw_trends as $trend)
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ $trend->name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is a multi-dimensional array, Assuming you want the trends in the first item, use this:

```
@foreach ($tw_trends[0]->trends as $trend)
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ $trend->name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Duh! I think I knew this, emphasis on think. :p Thanks!